# Javascript when adding row how do i get values from first row to second

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

i have a form and i am adding rows to add multiple data at once, problem is it is pretty redundant to rewrite some data in the rows. so i want values of first row carryover to second and so on.
[image]

my current Add row function

```
       function addRows()
        { 
            var table = document.getElementById('emptbl');
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var cellCount = table.rows[0].cells.length; 
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            for(var i =0; i <= cellCount; i++)
            {
                var cell = 'cell'+i;
                cell = row.insertCell(i);
                var copycel = document.getElementById('col'+i).innerHTML;
                cell.innerHTML=copycel;
                
            }
        }
```

table layout is something like this

```
 <table id="emptbl">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td id="col0">
                <label for="transports">Schedule Type:</label>
                  <select id="transports" name="schedule_type[]">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Type</option>
                  <option value="Weekday">Weekday</option>
                  <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                  <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
                  <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
                  <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                  <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                  <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                  <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                  <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
                  </select>
              </td>
```

Comment: Check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1728578/8494462) helps.

Comment: thanks alot this cloning works for everything besides the selectboxes

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: found workaround for selectbox not cloning. simply add onchange to selectbox and update function. and for cloning use link Shivam posted above.

```
  <select id="transports" name="schedule_type[]" onchange="update(this);">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Type</option>
            <option value="Weekday">Weekday</option>
            <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
            <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
            <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>  
            </select>

         function update(val){
          val.options[val.selectedIndex].setAttribute("selected","");
          }
```